# Choices for combobox in a repeat

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I've got a view that contains documents with various questions I want answered about Purchase Orders.

Using a repeat, I list all the questions. There are a few different kinds of questions, so I only render the answer field that I need based on the FieldType column value. I want to pull the choices for a combobox from the DialogChoices field on the question document.

I'm currently getting the choices showing as plain text on the next line after the empty combobox instead of as the selectItems. Where is my code going wrong?

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("FieldType") == "Dialog Box"; }]]></xp:this.rendered>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = rowData.getDocument();
            var choicesVector:java.util.Vector= doc.getItemValue("DialogChoices");
            var choices = [];
            // loop through the vector, doing push into the array
            for (i=0; i<choicesVector.size(); i++) {
                choices.push (choicesVector.elementAt(i))   
            };
        return choices;}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange, but a test database with the code above does not seem to give me strange results. Maybe it is because the data is in fact not an Vector but just a string?

Here are some tips :

The first thing you could change in your code is the loop to get all the data out of your field. Since the value property of a combobox already expects an array or vector you can change the code to something like:

```
 <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = rowData.getDocument();
           return  doc.getItemValue("DialogChoices");
            }]]>
        </xp:this.value>
```

But it would be even better to remove the getDocument call at all. If possible you can add a column to the view are you are using for the repeat's datasource. In this column you get the data from the field directory. This way you can use the viewentry's getColumnValue() which is a performance optimization. Something like:

```
<xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{try{
return rowData.getColumnValue("DialogChoices");
           }catch(e){// do something }]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
```

Comment: I had two problems. The first was a typo, spelling the field DailogChoices on the form. I must have also mis-spelled it in at least one test. Second, I was doing those gyrations with the vector. I have switched to rowData.getColumnValue("DialogChoices"); and it works as intended. Thanks!